# He dropped by my house so that he gave me the invitation card

Tags: grammar

I live in Korea. But I lived in the US for 4years and I probably know English as much as I need. My friend asked me if that sentence was wrong or right. And I said it was wrong. I thought if the sentence wanted to be right it should have been written as 'He dropped by my house so that he could give me the invitation card.'

Answer (score 1):

The sentence:

> He dropped by my house so that he gave me the invitation card.

is indeed non-natural, and at least arguably ungrammatical. but the suggestion:

> He dropped by my house so that he could give me the invitation card.

while it avoids the tense problem with "so that he gave me" is still not phrased as a native speaker would be likely to word this.

- First of all, at least in US-English "invitation card" is not a usual phrase -- a written or printed card inviting a person to some event is simply called "an invitation"
- Secondly, "so that he could give me" feels a bit awkward. "in order to give me" would be more common, but just "to give me" would be more common yet.

Thus, more plausible forms would be:

> - He dropped by my house in order to give me the invitation.
> - He dropped by my house to give me the invitation.

Comment: again, a pointless unexplained drive-by downvote.

Comment: The answer above is correct.